# Overlapping sub-task of Gantt chart

Tags: jfreechart, gantt-chart

Is there any way I can overlap the sub-tasks of Gantt chart?

Currently, the first sub-task is shrinked to end just when second sub-task starts. Only option I see right now is to rewrite the whole `drawTasks()` method of `GanttRenderer`.

A nice to have would be to show the overlapped section in a different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the fix.
Turnsout, the subtasks was already overlapped. Decreasing the color saturation by overriding `getItemPaint()` did the Job.